# "Ich gehe zu nicht einem einzigen Termin" oder "Ich gehe nicht zu einem einzigen Termin"?

Tags: grammar-identification, negation

Die Negationspartikel "nicht" steht meines Wissens nach *außerhalb* des Adverbials (->  Dudenband 4 2009, Randnummer 1434), wonach "nicht zu einem" richtig sein müsste, aber komischerweise hört sich "zu nicht einem" genauso richtig für mich an.

> 1. Ich gehe zu nicht einem einzigen Termin.
> 2. Ich gehe nicht zu einem einzigen Termin.

Ist die Regel, an die ich mich erinnere, hier nicht richtig? Natürlich muss "ein" stärker betont werden, wenn "nicht" davor steht - Aber muss es vor oder nach der Präposition stehen?

Und natürlich weiß ich, dass eigentlich "zum" bevorzugt wird, hier will ich aber absichtlich "ein" benutzen für besondere Betonung.

Comment: Die normalste Ausdrucksweise ist natürlich "zu keinem einzigen Termin". Die Antwort unten ist aber korrekt, dass das beides grammatisch akzeptable Wortfolgen sind.

Answer (score 3):

Beides ist möglich, weil das grammatisch unterschiedlich ist. Das Wort "nicht" bezieht sich bei den beiden Varianten jeweils auf unterschiedliche Teile des Satzes.

Bei "Ich gehe nicht zu einem einzigen Termin." wird das Verb "gehe" negiert, oder die ganze Präpositionalphrase "zu einem einzigen Termin", das ist nicht eindeutig. Bei "Ich gehe zu nicht einem einzigen Termin." wird "ein" oder "ein einziger" negiert; "nicht einem einzigen"  entspricht "keinem einzigen".

Bei diesem Beispielsatz spielt das alles ohne weiteren Kontext für die Bedeutung praktisch keine Rolle, deshalb sind beide Varianten möglich.

Ein ähnliches Beispiel, bei dem die Reihenfolge aber eine Rolle spielt, ist:

> Ich fahre nicht für einen einzigen Termin in die Stadt. *(Aber für mehrere vielleicht schon.)*
> Ich fahre für nicht einen einzigen Termin in die Stadt. *(Also auf keinen Fall. Es gibt keinen einzigen Termin, für den ich in die Stadt fahren würde.)*

Comment: Ne. Wenn ich 'einen einzigen Termin' negieren wollte, müsste es "Ich gehe zu einem einzigen Termin nicht" heißen. Nicht negiert im Allgemeinen den vorhergehenden Satzteil.

Comment: @planetmaker: der Kommentar ist in der gegenwärtigen Knappheit wenig hilfreich, weil er sich auf ein anderes Szenario (in dem *in die Stadt* nicht vorkommt) bezieht, nämlich einen von mehreren Terminen ausfallen zu lassen.

Comment: @planetmaker: Was heißt denn .A.? Wenn "nicht" innerhalb einer präpositionalen Bestimmung hinter "für" oder "zu" (als Präposition) steht, ergibt diese Regel nicht den geringsten Sinn. Ich denke, das wird mit nicht allzuviel Nachdenken klar.

Comment: Dann möchte ich aber deine Aufmerksamkeit auf Dudenband 4 (2009) Randnummer 1434 lenken. Dort steht, dass wenn nur ein Element einer Präpositionalphrase,  die Nominalphrase, fokussiert ist, die Negation vor der gesamten Präpositionalphrase steht. (links davon)

Comment: @EagleFliesBanana: guter Punkt. Ich habe es editiert. In "zu nicht einem einzigen Termin" wird nicht die ganze Nominalphrase negiert, sondern eigentlich nur "einem" oder "einem einzigen". "Ich gehe nicht zu einem einzigen Termin." ist grammatisch doppeldeutig, es kann entweder das Verb oder auch die ganze Präpositionalphrase verneinen. Was aber bei dem Satz inhaltlich auch dasselbe ist.

Comment: Neben "nicht" und "kein" können wir doch auch mit "nicht 'ein"  negieren. Da wir "kein" in der Phrase haben können, "nicht" aber alleine nicht, könnte es denn sein, dass "nicht ein" als Negation des Nomens benutzt werden darf? 
Also:  *Ich gehe zu nicht dem Haus.   Aber:  Ich gehe zu nicht 'einem Haus. 
Wobei "ein" natürlich stark betont werden muss.